# Why does Block Content doesn't display but only base.html does?

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance, frameworks

I'm trying to inherit a base.html template to another one, but the thing is that when I extend it, it only shows the base.html but it doesn't show the block content, here's the code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.register, name = "register")
]
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/register.html')
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>lalala</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
{% extends "app1/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<ol>
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>hola</li>
    <li>hola</li>
</ol>

{% endblock %}
```

The thing is that it doesn't show the ol, it only shows the h1 from the base.html

Comment: You need a `{% block content %}... {% endblock %}` (it will probably be empty) in the base template too, otherwise how does Django know where to put that content?

Comment: but it is right there, in the last block of code.

Comment: That's the child template. Your base template, in the snippet before, defines no such block. That's why it's not working.

Comment: So where should I put the block content?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just figured it out, you're a genius

Comment: @SebastianNin if you have an answer for your question, could you just quickly resolve it for us :)